# How to check available storage on an LTO 4 tape?

Tags: lto

How can I tell the amount of storage used and available on an LTO 4 tape?

I have a printout from the tape that shows blocks and the file length of each library.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to [this similar question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/853302/determine-remaining-capacity-of-lto-tape).

There is an attribute in LTO cartridge memory (LTO-CM or MAM). The attribute is "Remaining Capacity In Partition". You can read this value with LTO tape drive via SCSI command. You should take a look at this Linux bash script I created called [LTO-CM-Read](https://github.com/Kevin-Nakamoto/LTO-CM-Read).